# Word-wrap doesn't apply to div inside fieldset in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Tried in linux chrome 27.0.1453.93 and windows chrome 27.0.1453.94.  Example at http://jsfiddle.net/SruNd/4/.

CSS

```
.main {
    width : 100px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='main'>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            http://www.aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/ggg
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I've also tried this where the word-wrap property is applied directly to the inner div and the fieldset is a block element.

It seems to me like a chrome bug as I've also tried this in FireFox and it wraps as it should on the slashes, and without the fieldset it also does this correctly in Chrome.

I tried to submit a chrome bug report however the page is not accepting my submission right now due to a malformed HTTP request error.

If someone has any insight please help.  Thank you.

Comment: You should not use `word-wrap: break-word` for most types of character data, including URLs. URLs should only be broken at reasonable breaking points, e.g. after an `/`, but not within a path component for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this on fieldset tag:

```
fieldset
{
    min-width: auto;
}
```

In fact, this is due to the chrome's default property for fieldset :

```
min-width: -webkit-min-content;
```

Comment: I got an "invalid value" when using auto, but "0" worked (0 is what MDN states as the initial value).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `min-width` and a `max-width` to the div. Example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SruNd/9/)

Comment: This is equivalent to just setting a fixed width on the inner div, but the outer div uses a percentage size, which doesn't work when setting a percentage size on the inner div

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<div class='main'>
<fieldset>
    <div class="content">
        http://www.aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/ggg
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Css code

```
.content{
width : 100%;
border : 1px solid #000;
word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```