# max-width not working on anchor within fieldset

Tags: css, width, anchor, fieldset

I'm trying to build a page, whose contents always shall be within the visible width. This worked fine, until I added a fieldset.

For some reason, the anchor text will not break, when the anchor rests in a fieldset. Can anyone tell me
- why?
- how to circumvent this?

Example:

```
<fieldset>
  <a href="example.com">verylonglinktextthatmakesproblemsinsmallwindows</a>
</fieldset>
<a href="example.com">verylonglinktextthatbreaksmagicallyoutsidethefieldset</a>
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/myngsges/2/

Comment: Adding a 'min-width: auto;' seems to do it. Reference: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942338/word-wrap-doesnt-apply-to-div-inside-fieldset-in-chrome)

Comment: this works! Make it an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a 'min-width: auto;' seems to do it. Reference: [Word-wrap doesn't apply to div inside fieldset in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942338/word-wrap-doesnt-apply-to-div-inside-fieldset-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Add a space between some of the words, I’d say.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but neither does that really solve the problem, nor is it an option: 
in my case the anchor text is the href itself (needed) and very long.